# Probability of panel assignment

Tags: probability

I am trying to determine the probability of a "mixed panel" assignment (i.e., a panel of judges w/at least 1 woman).

Consider the following: A court has a total of 20 judges, 8 of whom are women. Panels of 5 judges are randomly drawn to decide any given case. What is the probability of drawing a panel on which at least 1 of the judges is female?

I realize this is a "simple" question, but it is beyond me. I would greatly appreciate a discussion of the steps required for its solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I previously had a [similar question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3650/1036), and the [hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) is applicable to your question as stated.

Answer (score 6):

There is a large and rich branch of mathematics, [combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics), devoted to solving such problems.  The most important step used here is to recognize that "at least one female" is more simply characterized as "not all males."  Details follow.

---

The name for the number of distinct 5-member panels from a pool of 20 judges is the "binomial coefficient," $\binom{20}{5}$.  We will worry later about how to compute this.  All probabilities involving 5-member panels of these judges will be fractions with this number in the denominator.  Computing a probability is a matter of counting which panels are described by an event; that will go in the numerator.

The all-male panels are drawn from a smaller pool of just 20-8 = 12 judges.  There are therefore $\binom{12}{5}$ of them.  The remainder of the possible panels, equal in number to $\binom{20}{5} - \binom{12}{5}$, have at least one female.  Therefore the desired probability is

$$\Pr(\text{Panel with a female judge}) = \frac{\binom{20}{5} - \binom{12}{5}}{\binom{20}{5}}.$$

To compute the binomial coefficients, consider that the number of *ordered* sequences of 5 people out of 20 equals $20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16$ because there are 20 ways to pick the first in the panel, 19 remaining people from whom to choose the second, and so on.  Any panel of 5 people determines $5! = 5\cdot 4 \cdots 2 \cdot 1$ such orderings.  Therefore $\binom{20}{5} = 20\cdots 16 / (5 \cdots 1) = 15504.$  Likewise $\binom{12}{5} = 792$.  The desired probability is

$$\frac{\binom{20}{5} - \binom{12}{5}}{\binom{20}{5}} = \frac{15504 - 792}{15504} = \frac{613}{646}.$$

Comment: "not all males" rather than "no males"?